# How can I copy data from several input json objects to one output object with jq?

Tags: json, edit, jq

I have a file where each line is an array of json objects, like:

```json
[
  {
    "ts": "2017-06-13 16:59:35,778"
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "path": "/1497365920809-31368-6D8E756916AE1",
    "messageAttributes": {
      "some_obsolete_data": "1497365975532",
      "more_obsolete_data": "20",
      "c": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 40,
    "path": "/1497365920809-31368-6D8E756916AE1",
    "messageAttributes": {
      "some_obsolete_data": "some text",
      "data_that_I_Need": "Name,1,Text,1497365975568"
    }
  }
]
```

The first object of each array will always be a "timestamp" that I need but the following objects may or may not be of interest.

Now I need to get jq to convert each line to an array of json objects containing the timestamp and the `data_that_I_Need`, like

```json
[
  {
    "ts": "2017-06-13 16:59:35,778",
    "id": 40,
    "path": "/1497365920809-31368-6D8E756916AE1",
    "messageAttributes": {
      "data_that_I_Need": "Name,1,Text,1497365975568"
    }
  }
]
```

By doing

```sh
jq '
  .[]                                                 | 
  select(.messageAttributes.data_that_I_Need != null) |
  {
    id   : .id, 
    path : .path, 
    messageAttributes: { 
      dataThat_I_Need: .messageAttributes.data_that_I_Need
    }
  }
' <my_file.txt
```

I can filter out the obsolete data.

But how can I add the "ts" field from the first object as a field in the output?

#### UPDATE

Looks like I can set a variable in the beginning of the program that I can use for all following objects...

```sh
jq '
  .[0].ts as $ts                                      |
  .[]                                                 |
  select(.messageAttributes.data_that_I_Need != null) |
  {
    ts   : $ts, 
    id   : .id, 
    path : .path, 
    messageAttributes: { 
      dataThat_I_Need: .messageAttributes.data_that_I_Need
    }
  }
' <my_file.txt
```

Comment: thanks for formatting @Thor :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in the UPDATE is perfectly fine, but here is a variant that illustrates a couple of points, notably that no variable is needed and that `{x}` can be used as an abbreviation for `{x: .x}`:

```
.[0] 
+ (.[]
   | select(.messageAttributes.data_that_I_Need != null)
   | {id, 
      path,
      messageAttributes: {dataThat_I_Need: .messageAttributes.data_that_I_Need}} )
```